# I want to load different images to a div, from links

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, html, load

Hiya, very very new to jQuery and surviving on your wonderful tutorials.

I'm working on my portfolio website, and have a list of projects that uses jQuery's load function to load descriptions of each project into a separate div when clicked. Within each description is a set of numeric links, say 1-5, which I want to display relevant images into another separate div when clicked. My problem so far is that I can't reuse the load function because it overwrites it's intiial use, and doesn't seem to want to be echo'd into the php file that holds all my project descriptions.

Is there a way round this?

Comment: Could you post some of your existing code?

Answer (score 5):

I'm only guessing because I haven't seen your code, but when you dynamically load content using ajax, any javascript inside the new content will not get executed.

The best way around this would be to use [jQuery's live function](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to target the links inside the newly loaded content which replaces the image src when clicked - there is no need to use load to grab an image. Here is some example code:

Main page javascript (I didn't include the load function)

```
$('.project').live('click',function(){
 newImg = $(this).attr('data-img');
 $('#content img.projectImg').attr('src', newImg);
})
```

HTML in loaded content

```
<div id="content">

<!-- this content was dynamically loaded -->
<img class="projectImg" style="float:right"/>
<ul>
 <li class="project" data-img="project1.jpg">Project 1</li>
 <li class="project" data-img="project2.jpg">Project 2</li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use pure JavaScript for doing that, no need of jquery

For example, dynamically changing the image or text:

```
document.getElementById('Image_tag_ID').src = 'http:\\ bla-bla';
or
document.getElementById('Div_tag_ID').innerHTML = '<h1>Hello</h1>';
```